Does a crit fail on a Telekinetic Maneuver make you fall prone?
The Telekinetic Maneuver spell lets you Trip an enemy with a spell attack roll. If you get a crit failure on a Trip, you fall prone.
Obviously it's a little ridiculous for a telekinetic trip to make you fall prone, but using a very strict reading of the rules, do you fall prone when you critically fail on a Trip using Telekinetic Maneuver?

Yes, you fall
It allows you to Trip, and makes no modifications to that so you fall on a critical failure.
Why is it ridiculous? You're throwing out a "rush of telekinetic power" if you screw that up, why would it not be as disastrous as throwing out a rush of muscle power?

Rules-wise it makes sense because it says you just perform the action but with a spell check instead of athletics check.  But thinking of real world applications the failure in Trip makes sense because you are moving your body.  With telekinesis there doesn't seem to be a physical link to your body and no reason for you to fall prone on a failed spell check.  What other time when you use telekinesis is it possible to affect your physical body from interacting with what you're manipulating?

@JasonGoemaat: It would appear to have worldbuilding implications, in terms of how magic works, like that at least some of the force you exert with your mind has a reaction force on your body.

As someone who has seen telekinesis fail in TV, games, and comics: I agree.
